# Getting clipboard data from remote computer

Tags: c#, winforms

Using C#, is there a way to get the clipboard data that is on a remote machine ?
I am remoting into another computer using Remote Desktop, I run an application on it that copies some text onto the clipboard, from my desktop I have a C# winform application that needs to make use of the clipboard data on that remote machine.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Remote desktop can be configured to share the clipboard: https://i.imgur.com/pjFg2zk.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Clipboard object in C#, Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2thcsx4(v=vs.110).aspx

```
//Set data to clipboard
Clipboard.SetData(format, users);
//Get data from clipboard
List<User> result = null;
if (Clipboard.ContainsData(format)){
    result = (List<User>)Clipboard.GetData(format);
}
//Clear clipboard
Clipboard.Clear();
```

Comment: The question asks about retrieving the clipboard content from a **remote computer via Remote Desktop**. How does a link to the documentation for Clipboard answer that question?

Comment: @Ken pls understand the question, he wants to access clipboard data on the remote machine using the application in that remote machine.

Comment: No he doesn't: "from my desktop I have a C# winform application that needs to make use of the clipboard data on that remote machine". Pls understand the question.